# How should I integrate facebook ads to flutter app correctly?

Tags: flutter, facebook, admob, facebook-ads

I have a flutter application and by using pub dev documnetation I set facebook ads integration.However, I can not create ads on meta developer account.Whenever I create a account all of sudden, facebook bans my account.There is no exact reason.
[image]

Every time I use admob ads,but my admob account has been banned also.
After uploading my project to play store / apple store ads worked for a week ,then it stopped.
Can I create new admob account and link my app to new account?

I have a look varios documentations for finding obvious explanation for this problem,but it is not enough